# Where to run collectstatic when deploying django app to heroku using docker?

Tags: django, docker, heroku, static-files

I am deploying a Django app to Heroku using Docker. When I put `RUN manage.py collectstatic --noinput` in the Dockerfile, it fails because there is no value set for the environment variable `DJANGO_SECRET_KEY`. My understanding is that this is because config vars aren't available during build time.

When I run collectstatic as a release command, it works without error, and successfully copies the static files. However, when I hit the app url, it returns a 500 error because the static files can't be found. I believe this is because the release command is run as a dyno on an ephemeral filesystem, and the copied files are therefore not found.

It seems to be a catch-22. Putting collectstatic in the Dockerfile fails because there are no config variables available, but putting it as a release command fails because only file changes from the build phase are saved?

What to do?

Here are my collectstatic settings in settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    ...
]
...
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'backend.storage.WhiteNoiseStaticFilesStorage'
```

Dockerfile

```
# Pull base image
FROM python:3.7-slim

# Set environment varibles
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Set work directory
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code

# Install dependencies
RUN pip install pipenv
COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock /code/
RUN pipenv install --system

# Copy project
COPY . /code/

## collect static files
RUN mkdir backend/staticfiles

# This fails because DJANGO_SECRET_KEY can't be empty
RUN python manage.py --noinput
```

heroku.yml

```
build:
  docker:
    web: Dockerfile
run:
  web: gunicorn backend.config.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT
```

Comment: They say it runs automatically during a build; https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets#collectstatic-during-builds
Also you could set the settings module in your dockerfile; `ENV DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=project.settings.build`

Comment: It doesn't automatically run when you are building a Docker container -- the link applies only if you aren't using Docker.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

After confirming with Heroku support, this does indeed appear to be a bit of a catch-22.

The solution was to put `collectstatic` in the Dockerfile so that it runs during build time and the files persist.

We got around not having a secret key config var by setting a default secret key using the `get_random_secret_key` function from Django.

The run phase uses the secret key from the Heroku config vars, so we aren't actually changing the secret key every time -- the default only applies to the build process. `collectstatic` doesn't index on the secret key, so this is fine.

In settings.py

```
from django.core.management.utils import get_random_secret_key
...
SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('DJANGO_SECRET_KEY', default=get_random_secret_key())
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I've wasted hours trying to get static files to work on Heroku! This is a wonderfully elegant solution.

Comment: Oh man I wish I had found that post 2 days ago !

Comment: Off topic: does it make sense to run `collectstatic` at all when inside a docker?

Comment: I also initially solved it this way, but my situation changed because I was trying to serve static files from S3 bucket and for that I needed additional ENV variables since the `collectstatic` needs to actually upload the static files to the bucket. Therefore the docker file gets bloated by many ARG and ENV lines and I need to do a bash for loop loading the variables from `.env` and passing them to `--build-args`. I do not like this at all. I will have to come up with smt else. Any ideas? Maybe the solution is indeed to run `collectstatic` just before the build so the bucket is up to date.

Comment: @shallowThought Why do you think it has no sense?

Answer (score 8):

I don't use heroku so can't test, but you should be able to run collect static before you run the app;

Dockerfile

```
# Pull base image
FROM python:3.7-slim

# Set environment varibles
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Set work directory
WORKDIR /code/

# Install dependencies
RUN pip install pipenv
COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock .
RUN pipenv install --system

# Copy project
COPY . .

# Collect static files
RUN python manage.py collectstatic --noinput

# run gunicorn
CMD gunicorn hello_django.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT
```

You could also not run `collectstatic` in your dockerfile, or event run the application because these can be ran by `heroku.yml`, for example;

```
build:
  docker:
    web: Dockerfile
  config:
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: project.settings
run:
  web: gunicorn backend.config.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT
release:
  image: web
  command:
    - python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
```

You also shouldn't need to `mkdir` for your working directory. Just set `WORKDIR /code/` early in your dockerfile and after that things will run based on that directory.

There's a decent article on this here; https://testdriven.io/blog/deploying-django-to-heroku-with-docker/

Comment: With collectstatic in the Dockerfile the build fails because the django secret key is not available at build time for the collectstatic command. With the collectstatic as an release command it will build and release successfully but can't actually find the static files, I believe because files created during release don't persist. That article is a puzzle; I'm wondering if the author never actually tested it.

Comment: @RyanKnight But you'll notice I've shown the addition of the settings module as an environment variable which would allow django to load the settings & execute the command.

Comment: Yup, tried that, doesn't work. The problem is that config vars aren't available at build time on Heroku: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/build-docker-images-heroku-yml#release-configuring-release-phase

Comment: @RyanKnight how about passing config variables from `heroku.yml` for the build? (I've updated my answer to include this)

Comment: The problem when running as part of the build process isn't finding the settings file; I've got a default path set for that in `manage.py` so that's never been an issue. The problem is accessing environment variables that are set through Heroku config vars. The one config var that fails with collectstatic is the django secret key, because it returns "", but a value is needed.

Comment: @markwalker_ I followed the article set up and was getting the same problem. the release command `collectstatic` was not persisting the staticfiles folder of my project after release. @Ryan Knight how did later get around this? thanks.

Comment: For those running into an issue still that is just because your project needs a SECRET_KEY set and if you are using environment variables, that is not the case with this provided snippet. You can however just use a better architecture and avoid that problem entirely though. Option 1 is to create a temporary and false key (not recommended) or you can use something like AWS SSM where it is immediately available :)

Answer (score 2):

You can prefix commands with dummy environment variables

```
RUN DJANGO_SECRET_KEY=secret python manage.py collectstatic --no-input
```