# Django static files are not loaded when deploying on Heroku using Docker and Whitenoise

Tags: python, django, docker, heroku

I'm trying to deploy a django app on Heroku (using [Whitenoise](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/)), and all works fine except for the static files. The [sample project](https://github.com/motasay/django-heroku-staticfiles) just shows a header "Home" on the front page. If the css file is loaded correctly then the header will have the red colour, otherwise it will be black.

I got the above project to work in a `virtualenv`, a `Docker` container, with `DEBUG=False`, but [I could not make it work on Heroku](https://evening-lowlands-39080.herokuapp.com) for some reason (The header would be Red if the CSS loaded correctly).

I tried to use the `django-heroku` as suggested by the [Heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-python#python-deployment-flow) but it starts throwing 500 server error, and when checking the `heroku logs` it says manifest not found for [the css file](https://github.com/motasay/django-heroku-staticfiles/blob/master/pages/static/pages/css/base.css), which seems to be because it sets `STATICFILES_STORAGE` to a different value.

Is there something setup incorrectly in the [settings](https://github.com/motasay/django-heroku-staticfiles/blob/master/hello_project/settings.py) or the [yml](https://github.com/motasay/django-heroku-staticfiles/blob/master/heroku.yml) files? Or perhaps because I'm deploying a Docker file (as opposed to a `Procfile`) I need to use different settings?

**Update 1:**

As suggested in the comments. I tried to follow what's done in [this tutorial](https://testdriven.io/blog/deploying-django-to-heroku-with-docker/), which has two additional things done:

1. Setting `STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'`
2. Running `heroku plugins:install @heroku-cli/plugin-manifest`

When doing this, now I get a different HTTP 500 error:

> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/whitenoise/base.py:115: UserWarning: No directory at: /django-heroku-staticfiles/staticfiles/

Now I think the problem is clear. So I started running some commands on the heroku instance:

```
$ heroku run ls -l /django-heroku-staticfiles
Running ls -l /django-heroku-staticfiles on ⬢ evening-lowlands-39080... up, run.5553 (Free)
total 160
-rw------- 1 u35232 dyno    179 May 30 12:21 Dockerfile
-rw------- 1 u35232 dyno 131072 May 30 12:21 db.sqlite3
-rw------- 1 u35232 dyno    235 May 30 12:21 docker-compose.yml
drwx------ 2 u35232 dyno   4096 May 30 12:21 hello_project
-rw------- 1 u35232 dyno    182 May 30 12:21 heroku.yml
-rwx------ 1 u35232 dyno    633 May 30 12:21 manage.py
drwx------ 4 u35232 dyno   4096 May 30 12:21 pages
-rw------- 1 u35232 dyno     93 May 30 12:21 requirements.txt
drwx------ 2 u35232 dyno   4096 May 30 12:21 templates

$ heroku run python manage.py collectstatic --clear --noinput
Running python manage.py collectstatic --clear --noinput on ⬢ evening-lowlands-39080... up, run.9686 (Free)

131 static files copied to '/django-heroku-staticfiles/staticfiles', 413 post-processed.

$ heroku run ls -l /django-heroku-staticfiles
Running ls -l /django-heroku-staticfiles on ⬢ evening-lowlands-39080... up, run.3303 (Free)
total 160
-rw------- 1 u20456 dyno    179 May 30 12:21 Dockerfile
-rw------- 1 u20456 dyno 131072 May 30 12:21 db.sqlite3
-rw------- 1 u20456 dyno    235 May 30 12:21 docker-compose.yml
drwx------ 2 u20456 dyno   4096 May 30 12:21 hello_project
-rw------- 1 u20456 dyno    182 May 30 12:21 heroku.yml
-rwx------ 1 u20456 dyno    633 May 30 12:21 manage.py
drwx------ 4 u20456 dyno   4096 May 30 12:21 pages
-rw------- 1 u20456 dyno     93 May 30 12:21 requirements.txt
drwx------ 2 u20456 dyno   4096 May 30 12:21 templates
```

Why is `staticfiles` not getting created? Maybe I need to run the command through Docker? Sorry I'm new to Docker, Django, and Heroku, so I might be missing something obvious.

Comment: I think django-heroku overwrites your `STATIC_URL` and `STATIC_ROOT`. Have you tried adding `STATICFILES_DIRS` so you can explicitly say where your files are? Something like: 

`STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    ('pages', os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'pages/static')),
)`

Comment: Hm... deploy Django with Docker to Heroku might require extra steps. This (tutorial) [https://testdriven.io/blog/deploying-django-to-heroku-with-docker/] also suggests adding `STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'`

Comment: Thank you @OriginalBBQSauce for the link! Two extra things seem to be done in this article: 1) setting `STATICFILES_STORAGE` and installing a `plugin-manifest`. I'll try to add these and report back.

Comment: Just tried these and now there is an 500 error: `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/whitenoise/base.py:115: UserWarning: No directory at: /django-heroku-staticfiles/staticfiles/` which is self explanatory. Now the question is why doesn't `collectstatic` create this dir? Thanks again I'll update the question with these details.

Comment: Actually... it's searching for a `staticfiles` folder inside another `staticfiles`. That´s a bit weird!

Comment: I don't think so. The name of the main folder contains `staticfiles` at the end so it looks a bit confusing sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [@Original BBQ Sauce](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2533340/original-bbq-sauce), this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59719175/where-to-run-collectstatic-when-deploying-django-app-to-heroku-using-docker), and [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/grdk7z/django_docker_heroku_and_a_staticfiles_hell/fs0fair) the problem is finally solved. It's related to where/when we run `collectstatic`. Initially I was running it as a `release command` in the `heroku.yml` file, which was not creating the staticfiles directory for some reason. I was doing it this way as is done in the Django for Professionals book.

Now, if that command is run in the Dockerfile instead, the staticfiles directory is created and [all should work fine](https://evening-lowlands-39080.herokuapp.com). The repo now has the new, working settings.