# ValueError: Missing staticfiles manifest entry on Heroku with Docker, django-pipeline, whitenoise

Tags: django, docker, heroku, django-pipeline, whitenoise

I am trying to deploy a Django project on Heroku using Docker, django-pipeline, and whitenoise. The container builds successfully, and I see that `collectstatic` generates the expected files inside `container-name/static`. However, upon visiting any page I receive the following 500 error:

```
ValueError: Missing staticfiles manifest entry for 'pages/images/favicons/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png'
```

Below are my `settings.py`, `Dockerfile`, and `heroku.yml`. Since I'm also using django-pipeline, one thing I'm unsure of is what setting to use for `STATICFILES_STORAGE`? I tried

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'pipeline.storage.PipelineStorage'
```

but that lead to the file paths 404ing.

Any advice is appreciated. Thank you.

```
#settings.py
...
# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = env.bool("DJANGO_DEBUG", default=False)

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.herokuapp.com', 'localhost', '127.0.0.1']

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.admindocs",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "django.contrib.sites",
    # Third-party
    "allauth",
    "allauth.account",
    "debug_toolbar",
    "django_extensions",
    "pipeline",
    "rest_framework",
    "whitenoise.runserver_nostatic",
    "widget_tweaks",
    # Local
    ...
]
MIDDLEWARE = [
    "debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware",
    ...
]

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = "/static/"
# STATICFILES_DIRS = [str(BASE_DIR.joinpath("code/static"))]
STATIC_ROOT = str(BASE_DIR.joinpath("static"))

MEDIA_URL = "/media/"

MEDIA_ROOT = str(BASE_DIR.joinpath("media"))

# django-pipeline config
STATICFILES_STORAGE = "whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage"
DEBUG_PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS = True
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder",
    "pipeline.finders.PipelineFinder",
)
...
```

```
# Dockerfile
# Pull base image
FROM python:3.8

# Set environment variables and build arguments
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs build-essential

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /code
COPY . /code/
RUN npm install sass --dev
RUN npm install yuglify --dev
RUN npm install
RUN mkdir static
RUN mkdir staticfiles

# Install dependencies
COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock /code/
# Figure out conditional installation of dev dependencies
# Will need to remove --dev flag for production
RUN pip install pipenv && pipenv install --system --dev
```

```
# heroku.yml
setup:
  addons:
  - plan: heroku-postgresql
build:
  docker:
    web: Dockerfile
release:
  image: web
  command:
    - python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
run:
  web: gunicorn config.wsgi
```

### UPDATE

Based on ENDEESA's response to [this similar SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38627393/docker-django-404-for-web-static-files-but-fine-for-admin-static-files), I updated my settings to the following, since my static files are stored inside `pages/static/pages`:

```
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATICFILES_DIRS = [str(BASE_DIR.joinpath("pages/static"))]
STATIC_ROOT = str(BASE_DIR.joinpath("static"))
```

I also noticed that my top-level `urls.py` file included the following line:

```
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

As I understand it, this is useful for serving static files in development, but should not be used in production, so I moved it to only be added if DEBUG is True. But alas, the error persists.

More mysteriously, when I run

```
python manage.py findstatic <file-path> --verbosity 2
```

the file is found:

```
Found 'images/favicons/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png' here:
  /code/pages/static/images/favicons/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png
  /code/pages/static/images/favicons/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png
Looking in the following locations:
  /code/pages/static
  /code/static
  /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static
  /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/debug_toolbar/static
  /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django_extensions/static
  /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/static
```

So why am I still getting `ValueError: Missing staticfiles manifest entry`?

Answer (score 5):

### SOLVED

At long last, I came to the following solution. My main issues were:

- the static files appeared to be collected during the release command, but the actual `STATIC_ROOT` dir was empty in my container. I'm not sure why. My solution was to NOT run `collectstatic` as a release command in `heroku.yml`, and instead do so in `Dockerfile`.
- NOTE: in order to `collectstatic` in my `Dockerfile` I needed to set a default for all environment variables, including `SECRET_KEY`, the latter for which I did using `get_random_secret_key()` from `django.core.management.utils`. Thank you to [Ryan Knight](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6378553/ryan-knight) for [illustrating this here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59719175/where-to-run-collectstatic-when-deploying-django-app-to-heroku-using-docker).
- In addition to my `settings.py` needing a default secret key, my final static files settings were as shown below.
- Since I'm using `django-pipeline`, my `js` files weren't loading correctly with `whitenoise` storage options. I wound up using `pipeline.storage.PipelineStorage` instead.
- It turned out I did not need to set `STATICFILES_DIRS` at all. Previously I was setting it as:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    str(BASE_DIR.joinpath("pages/static")),
    str(BASE_DIR.joinpath("staticfiles")),]
```

Both were unnecessary because `app_name/static/app_name` is the [default place Django will look for static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files) already, and I wasn't actually storing additional non-app-specific files in `root/staticfiles`. So I removed this setting.

- In `heroku.yml` I removed the release command for `collectstatic`.
- On the Settings page of my Heroku app's admin, I added a config variable for `DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC`, set to `1`.

```
# Dockerfile
# Pull base image
FROM python:3.8

# Set environment variables and build arguments
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs build-essential

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /code
COPY . /code/
RUN npm install sass --dev
RUN npm install yuglify --dev
RUN npm install

# Install dependencies
COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock /code/
RUN pip install pipenv && pipenv install --system

# Collect static files here instead of in heroku.yml so they end up in /code/static, as expected in the app
RUN python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
```

```
# settings.py
...
from django.core.management.utils import get_random_secret_key
SECRET_KEY = env("DJANGO_SECRET_KEY", default=get_random_secret_key())
...
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = str(BASE_DIR.joinpath("static"))
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'pipeline.storage.PipelineStorage'
DEBUG_PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS = True
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder",
    "pipeline.finders.PipelineFinder",
)
...
```

```
# heroku.yml
setup:
  addons:
  - plan: heroku-postgresql
build:
  docker:
    web: Dockerfile
release:
  image: web
run:
  web: gunicorn config.wsgi
```

Project structure, in case it's helpful:

```
config
  settings.py
  ...
pages
  static
    pages
      scss
      js
      images
static
Dockerfile
heroku.yml
docker-compose.yml
...
```

Best of luck to anyone else battling the deployment gods. May the odds be ever in your favor, and don't give up!

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution! Did you also get to a solution for production env variables? I mean, without having to expose environment variables at build time.

Answer (score 3):

This works! Comment out STATICFILES_STORAGE and type the code below.

#STATICFILES_STORAGE = "whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage"

```
WHITENOISE_USE_FINDERS = True
WHITENOISE_MANIFEST_STRICT = False
WHITENOISE_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
```